# CSS parsing using python using regex or anything else?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to parse CSS file to change style fo html. 
Look at the example CSS text as follow :

```
p.FM_table_cell_body308 {
      margin-left:0.000pt;
      margin-right:0.000pt;
      text-align:left;
      text-indent:0.000pt;
}

p.FM_table_cell_body309 {
      margin-left:0.000pt;
      margin-right:0.000pt;
      text-align:left;
      text-indent:0.000pt;
}

p.FM_table_cell_body {
      margin-left:0.000pt;
      margin-right:0.000pt;
      text-align:left;
      text-indent:0.000pt;
}
```

I want to change the word 'left' of 'text-align:left;' to 'center' in every under 'p.FM_table_cell_body*** {'  (*** is number).

So, this is what i am looking foward as follow :

```
p.FM_table_cell_body308 {
      margin-left:0.000pt;
      margin-right:0.000pt;
      text-align:center;
      text-indent:0.000pt;
}

p.FM_table_cell_body309 {
      margin-left:0.000pt;
      margin-right:0.000pt;
      text-align:center;
      text-indent:0.000pt;
}

p.FM_table_cell_body {   # this has no number so should pass
      margin-left:0.000pt;
      margin-right:0.000pt;
      text-align:left;   # no change
      text-indent:0.000pt;
}
```

And it's what i am coding so far as below :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import glob2  
import re

with open ("C:\\TEST\\HTML\\Output_sample1\\Responsive HTML5\\Output.css","r",encoding="utf-8") as file_css :
    with open ("C:\\TEST\\HTML\\Output_sample1\\Responsive HTML5\\Output_test.css","wt",encoding="utf-8") as file_css_text_align :
        lines_css = file_css.readlines()
        for i_css, line_css in enumerate(lines_css[:-1]):
            try :
                FM_number_css = re.findall('FM_table_cell_body[1-9][0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?', line_css)
                text_align_content = lines_css[i_css + 3]
                if FM_number_css and text_align_content == 'text-align:left;':
                    text_align_content = text_align_content.split(':')
                    text_align_content.remove('left;\n')
                    text_align_content.insert(1, 'center;\n')
                    new_text_align_content = ':'.join(text_align_content)

                    file_css_text_align.write(str(new_text_align_content))
                 else :
                     file_css_text_align.write(str(line_css))
             except : 
                 pass
```

but this code i am trying to make doesn't work right.
this code changes not this(text-align:left;) but (p.FM_table_cell_body*** {) to text-align:center; .

Would you guys give me any advice for me ?

Thanks have a great day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a single regular expression with `re.sub`: search for

```
(p\.FM_table_cell_body\d+ {[^}]+text-align:)left
```

to capture everything in a section, up to `text-align:` in a group, then *match* `'left'`, and replace with the first captured group plus `'center'`, thereby replacing `'left'`s with `'center'`s:

https://regex101.com/r/r0dDBz/1

```
input = '''p.FM_table_cell_body308 {
      margin-left:0.000pt;
      margin-right:0.000pt;
      text-align:left;
      text-indent:0.000pt;
}

p.FM_table_cell_body309 {
      margin-left:0.000pt;
      margin-right:0.000pt;
      text-align:left;
      text-indent:0.000pt;
}

p.FM_table_cell_body {
      margin-left:0.000pt;
      margin-right:0.000pt;
      text-align:left;
      text-indent:0.000pt;
}'''
print(re.sub(r'(p\.FM_table_cell_body\d+ {[^}]+text-align:)left', r'\1center', input))
```

Comment: Wow! what the heck... this is really good for real. Thank you so much!